# How to set the backcolors to transparent in PictureBoxes inside buttons in C#?

Tags: c#

So I put a picture box inside a button, it looks great when it it isn't hovered. However, when I do, this happen... I set the BackColor of it to Transparent but this happens when I hover on to it.

[image: Hovered button]

Comment: It suppose to be winforms, but in there you can not have [PictureBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox) inside a button. Can you clarify please? [Edit] question to add details, see also [mcve].

Comment: I just put it there. I dragged the pictureBox from the toolbox and just placed it there.

Comment: You can __overlay__ it as you did and then __transparency will not work__. Or you can __nest__ it; then some transparency will be faked. To nest __use code__ (`pbox.Parent = btn; pbox.Location = ..`) ! Only __containers__ will accept a dragged control as a child; button or pboxes are not containers; panels and groupboxes and then some are. Why can't you use the backgroundimage of the button??

Comment: Ohhhh man. Im so sorry I didn't think of that since I was just starting over in C#. It worked! The bgImage of the button. I feel so dumb and funny at the same time. hahahaha Thanks a lot.